# Warning: This repo has Git hooks. Using Git hooks on Windows requires sh.exe, but GitKraken couldn't find it

Tags: git, gitkraken

For one of my repos GitKraken displays this warning message: "This repo has Git hooks. Using Git hooks on Windows requires sh.exe, but GitKraken couldn't find it."

Does it matter? How to make GK find this sh.exe file? Or how to solve this otherwise?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This warning relates to **Git for Windows**.

Under Preferences --> General there is 'Path to sh.exe', you need to Browse and point this to wherever you've installed Git for Windows, which is typically:

**Program Files\Git\bin.**

Or perhaps:

**C:\Users[YOU]\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe**

Comment: Happy to help :)